# Root Android virtual device with Android 7.1.1

Tags: rooting, root-access, android-emulator, android-sdk, virtualization

I'm using the official Android SDK with the Android Emulator to create a virtual Android 7.1.1 (x86). I need to test a number of things, amongst others, some applications require root access to the device.

Now I know that I can `adb root` and I have a root shell, but that doesn't allow the apps I install to have root access.

I've researched this topic now for a while and have seen various approaches. Most answer haven been posted rather long ago.

I think it's quite odd that there's no option to toggle root - this is after all an SDK.

How do I root an Android virtual device, running Android 7.1.1, effectively allowing installed apps root access?

*edit:* I'd rather not resort to paid emulators like Genymotion if possible.

*edit2:* This is solely for personal use.

**edit3:** Genymotion appears to be a viable solution, as an alternative emulator. How come Android SDK/Emulator does not offers such a feature?

**edit4:** The answer by [xavier_fakerat](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/176400/194076) seems to work perfectly fine, however since Android Studio version 3.1 this doesn't seem to be a permanent rooting. Once the AVD is rebooted, root access is gone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**How to root android emulator (Android 7.1.1/ Nougat)**

I’m pleased to inform the community of  an easier way to root android emulator (run from standalone Android SDK)

**Requirements**:

- [SuperSU app (chainfire) latest version 2.82](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/codingcode/supersu/)
- [Recovery flashable.zip (contains su binary)](http://www.supersu.com/download)  (Here is alternative *mirror link* for flashable zip if the main link is not working : [Flashable zip super su 2.82 for all roms](https://mega.nz/#!7nRh2QCA!xHJydni2jzbqgCbfBUZUALLizKqMhlaBM75ifCC2hwI))

*Note: SuperSU is now deprecated, but this method still works to root the emulator, and more updates will be given for newer rooting methods.*

**Instructions**

1. **Install the SuperSu.apk**

- Install the SuperSu app firstly, just do drag and drop (if running latest emulator version or sideload through adb i.e `adb -e install supersu.apk`)
- After installing it, when you run it shows a screen as shown below indicating “There is no SU binary installed..”. This error just confirms the device is not yet rooted.

[image]

2. **Make emulator’ system partition writable**

- As it suggests, we need to give the emulator permission to write system files.
- Type the following code to accomplish this: `emulator.exe -avd {emulator_name} -writable-system`

*Note: Navigate to the **tools** folder where Android SDK is installed and open command prompt there by pressing shift and right clicking.*

3. **Pushing su binary in system directory**

- Extract the Recovery flashable.zip (containing the su binaries of different architectures)

**Important! Only use the su binary that matches your avd architecture e.g x86, arm etc.., and note the path where you extracted these binaries.**

- Make sure you are running adb as root and also you need to remount.
  Just enter these codes

`adb root`

`adb remount`

Now its time to push the su binary:

**This is the code I successfully used**:  `adb -e push C:\%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\rootemu\x86\su.pie /system/bin/su`

*(nevermind about my specific location of su binary, any location is okay as long there is no white space)*

If this fails try this pushing to this directory instead `/system/xbin/su`. Also for emulators running android 5.1 and below use the `su` and not `su.pie`

4. **Change permissions of the su binary**

- Next let’s do a bit of modification of the permissions of su binary. We have to do this in emulator device through adb:

  ```
  adb -e shell
  su root
  cd /system/bin
  chmod 06755 su
  ```

**Important!! Take note of su binary path (mine is /system/bin)**

5. **Setting the `install` directive on su binary and set a `daemon`**

Type the codes:

`su --install`

and for setting up daemon:

`su --daemon&`

**Important!! Take note of spacing**

6. **Setting SELinux to Permissive(i.e turning off SE Linux)**

- Finally turn off selinux through this code:

`setenforce 0`

That’s pretty much it!! Open SuperSU app and it may ask to update binaries, you can use Normal method.

Open any app requiring SU permissions just to double check and indeed SuperSU ask if you wish to grant it su permissions.

[image]

**Remarks**

Most content in reference was for older android versions and hence the reason for different commands and paths which I modified.

**Special acknowledgements;**

*Special gratitude to Irvin H, whose tutorial inspired me to create this guide after myself having failed countless times, and also after seeing the need for many users to root their emulators too. I hope this will also benefit a lot*

[Irvin H: Rooting the android emulator –on Android Studio 2.3((Android 4.4)](https://infosectrek.wordpress.com/2017/03/06/rooting-the-android-emulator/)

#Update

As commented by SaAtomic,

> This approach is still viable with Android Studio 3.0.1

After upgrading to emulator version `27.2.9` and above it now makes preserving root much easier through **snapshot feature** (if copying the system.img method isn't working):

Ideally it is more like hibernating the virtual device with config intact, hence everything is preserved.

> Snapshots
>
> You can now save multiple AVD snapshots for a given device
> configuration and choose which of the saved snapshots to load when you
> start the emulator. Starting a virtual device by loading a snapshot is
> much like waking a physical from a sleep state, as opposed to booting
> it from a powered-off state.

This implies the only requirement to start the emulator is adding the `-writable-system` parameter to the normal emulator `-avd [avdname]` command to start the emulator. (Running the emulator just with emulator -avd [avdname] doesn't launch the rooted version/copy or may lead to some error)

*Tested on API level 22*

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I didn't try it yet, but this seems to be a viable solution!

Comment: @SaAtomic, your steps are very useful,
More ever, One can also flash Supersu 2.82/Magisk using a custom recovery, e.g- TWRP , and can easily obtain root....
These works well on any 7.1.1 or 7.1.2 running devices....
Thank You..

Comment: I've just tested this with Android SDK 2.3.3 (AVD Manager) and virtual Pixel using Android 7.1.1. Works just as described right away. Thank you!

Comment: Update: This approach is still viable with Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: I tried your approach, but get error in the 3rd step.
I used: Android Studio 3.0.1 on Mac, Nexus 5X with Android 7.1, so the emulator name will be Nexus_5X_API_25 for your reference. On executing adb root as stated in 3rd step, I get the below error:
<br/>$<b>adb root</b><br/>
<b>adbd cannot run as root in production builds</b> Kindly let me know, if your approach still works at this moment. Thanks.

Comment: It is most likely that you're using a wrong emulator image you need to  use the `Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image` rather than `Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image`

Comment: Update: After the latest update of Android Studio to 3.1 the `su` binary is in `/system/xbin/su` for a Pixel AVD with Android 7.1.1 (API 25) and no matter what I try, the rooting is not persistent. After reboots the AVD is not rooted anymore.

Comment: $ adb remount                                                                                                   1 
Not running as root. Try "adb root" first.

Comment: @SaAtomicyou need to update emulator and use snaptop to boot

Comment: First link is dead