# Android virtual device 7.1.1 stuck on logo screen after root

Tags: root-access, android-emulator

I just rooted AVD following the procedure described [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171442/root-android-virtual-device-with-android-7-1-1).

everything goes fine and the AVD is being rooted and i can access system folders, but as soon as i restart the emulator, it will not boot up and stuck on android logo screen.

anybody knows the solution to solve the problem?

Comment: I suspect the system images are corrupted, have you updated the su binaries correctly? Try replacing with fresh system images

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, i am sure that the su binaries are updated correctly. i pressed "normal" when su asked for update and it prompted successfull update. i dident restart and checked for root. root was ok. replacing fresh copy of system image makes emulator run again, but unrooted and needs to root again, which the problem arises after first restart

Comment: Ok I understand, to preserve root try copying the system image from temp directory (AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidEmulator), rename it system.img and replace the default

Comment: Please follow-up the updates of the solution here: [Android Emulator: How to avoid boot loop after rooting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/180516/209414)

Comment: Thank you so much for hard work on solution. i will test it and send feedback