# Edit hosts file on android studio messed up my emulator

Tags: android-emulator, hosts

I had to edit my emulator' hosts file in order to connect to a local development environment. I have followed this steps:

Run the emulator:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -writable-system -avd Nexus_5_API_19
```

In another terminal/cmd prompt:

```
adb reboot

adb root

adb -s emulator-5554 remount

adb -s emulator-5554 pull /system/etc/hosts hosts

add the IP to host file

adb -s emulator-5554 push hosts /system/etc/hosts

adb reboot
```

Now whenever I try to start my emulator from AVD Manager it is not responding. I always have to start it with:

```
 ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -writable-system -avd Nexus_5_API_19
```

I mention that I work from High Sierra.

Mention: I have tried with `adb` to make my emulator `rw` but it did not allow me to push my hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

There is an other way to manipulate the /etc/hosts  (You need a **Linux** machine )

Use the system.img which come from Google

## go to your Android SDK home

1. cd $ANDROID_HOME

## find the right system.img for your emulator

2. sudo mount -w system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86_64/system.img

## edit the /etc/hosts

3. sudo vi /mnt/etc/hosts
4. sudo umount /mnt

Create an emulator (from Android Studio)

1. ASD Manager
2. → "Create Virtual Device"
3. → Nexus 5X
4. → Next
5. → Tab x86 Images
6. → Nougart - 25 - x86_64
7. → Next
8. → "AVD Name" : "Nexus 5X API 25 with WLAN hosts"
9. → Finish

I have gone this way because **emulator -writable-system -avd xx** didn't work in my environment. Also mounting the system.img in my ~/.android/avd/xxxx directory didn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

**Step by Step**

1. Don’t Create the AVD with **Google Play image.**
2. Use for example **Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image**.
3. Start the emulator with the following command…

   ```
   emulator.exe –avd <avd name> -writable-system
   ```

For example:

```
    C:\Users\ilyas.mamun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator.exe -avd Pixel_API_25 -writable-system

    emulator: WARNING: System image is writable
    HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
    audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'
    qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed
    audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
```

4. Root and Remount the AVD like the followings…

   ```
   C:\Users\ilyas.mamun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb root

   C:\Users\ilyas.mamun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb remount
   remount succeeded

   C:\Users\ilyas.mamun\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
   eneric_x86:/ # cd system
   generic_x86:/system # cd etc
   generic_x86:/system/etc # cat hosts
   127.0.0.1       localhost
   ::1             ip6-localhost

   generic_x86:/system/etc # echo "192.168.1.181     sandbox.dmoney.com.bd" >> hosts
   generic_x86:/system/etc # cat hosts

   127.0.0.1       localhost
   ::1             ip6-localhost
   192.168.1.181     sandbox.dmoney.com.bd
   generic_x86:/system/etc #
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the reason you can't remount adb as root is you are using a production emulator image rather that a debug image see: [ADB root is not working on emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43923996/7551330)

To overcome this try rooting your avd as [outlined here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/176400), then install a [hosts editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nilhcem.hostseditor&hl=en) to easily modify the hosts file. Try rebooting as usual as you still need to append with `-writable -system` for changes to persist.

This problem occurs because emulator from android studio has been changed and partition `/system` is **no longer writable between reboots**.

An alternative  workaround will be  to replace the original files in `<sdk_path>/system-images/android-xx/default/x86/system.img`.

- Copy the `system.img`: `cp /home/a/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-xx/default/x86/system.img ~/.android/avd/[avdname].avd/system-qemu.img`
- Put the new `system.img` in `.android/avd/avd name/`. Rename it to `system-qemu.img`, thus the emulator will use this new image instead of the original one, and this won't your other emulators.

Comment: Sorry for the late response I was away in the past few days. I have trie to copy the system.img but I cannot seem to find it in /home/a/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-xx/default/x86/system.img Cannot seem to find system-images anywhere actually

Comment: And I am not using a production image

Comment: I have successfully copied system.img but it reseted my hosts file

Comment: Sorry for late reply, did you update hosts after you root?

Comment: yes I did, and afterwords I have copied the system.img, now I have pulled the hosts file from the emulator and it no longer contains my edits

Comment: And if you start it with `-writable -system` are changes persisting? or nothing has changed?

Comment: Nothing has changed

Comment: mmm strange I will look into this

Comment: Is it possible to be caused by copying the system.img?

Comment: Perhaps!  Ok please verify this, see if you are boot the avd smoothly after rooting (this time don't copy system.img) and check changes in hosts