# Android emulator root option

Tags: emulators

I want to emulate a android smartphone on my pc. I already found the android emulator from andoid sdk manager but its look more like a programming tool so I am not sure if this is what I want.
I want an emulator that is able to install android with root permissions so I can install apk's like lucky patcher etc.
What can I use?

Comment: What OS are you using on PC? Yes you can use android sdk for this, and you can root using this [method](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/176400/209414)

Comment: Windows 10. And ok I will try this

Comment: Private users can use [Genymotion Emulator "Genymotion for fun"](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/) for free, their images are usually already rooted and it does not feel "like a programming tool".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android SDK is not necessarily for development only, you can simply download the standalone [Android SDK](https://dl.google.com/android/installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe) and [install it your your PC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429326/7551330).

After setting up your AVD simply, root it using this [method](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/176400/209414). This is a standard method that works for most applications (*except for a few requiring flashing .zips via recovery e.g Xposed, but I'm working on a fix for that*)

Note: To access API > 27 on your target AVD, you need to manually [upgrade the emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429889/7551330).

`

Comment: Does this work with android 9 too?

Comment: Yes it does after you [upgrade your emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51429889/7551330)

Comment: I didnt get it to work, I did everything like in the tutorial. I have sdk version 28+ installed but android 9 isnt starting at all and android 7 just hangs in the andoird screen :/

Comment: It doesnt work with the 28 version. After I tried the 27 version it worked.

Comment: I choose a google cpu/abi and now it is still loading after 10min with the google sing. Is this normal? I have a good pc btw

Comment: you should use intel images (x86) there are faster than arm, and yes api 28, 29 works

Comment: If you still aren't successful you can try @Robert method for genymotion

Comment: Yeah but I only saw a Trial and a Business Version on the genymotion site. Is there a Version for free? on my cpu/abi selection there was no ARM to select. I will try all cpu`s later. How long should it take to get past the "Google loading screen"? Edit: Oh I see he edit the link to the free Version. I will try it if I am back home.